# Failed to load resource in Node JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, node-modules

I am doing a tutorial trying to learn Node and Angular. I am completely new to this, I come from a LAMP stack environment so it's a whole new world to me and I feel completely lost.

I have installed Angular JS and included it in my HTML file but I keep getting this error

> http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:3000/app/app.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**EDIT:** I have tried some different approached but they're all pointing to the `/server/` directory.

```
var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
var appDir = path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename);
```

Both of these point to `/server/` directory.

My folders structure is as follows:

- /app

  - app.js
- /node_modules
- /server

  - server.js
- index.html

This is `server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/social');

app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("index.html", {root: '../'});
});

app.listen('3000', function() {
    console.log('Listening for localhost 3000');
});
```

This is `app.js`

```
(function() {
    angular.module('Social', []);
}());
```

This is `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Social">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Testing the test</p>
</body>

<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__dirname` is "The name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in." which is the directory `server.js` is in.

So when you are doing:

```
express.static(__dirname + '/app')
```

I think it is actually looking for `/server/app` which is not correct.

Comment: What should I be using instead?

Comment: You were correct. It was a mistake on my part, I had `server.js` nested inside the `/server/` dir when it should've been in the root directory. Moved it there and it's working now.